# Force the “Choose from the most used tags” meta box section to always be expanded

Tags: posts, functions, taxonomy, post-meta

I'm looking to have the "most used tags" link within the tag meta box on the post page always be expanded. Couldn't find any helpful plugins to use.

I did find [this previous post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45149/how-to-have-the-most-used-tags-taxonomy-always-expanded) but the function doesn't seem to be working anymore - I'm wondering if something has changed since that was in 2012.

Comment: Thanks @Castiblanco - It's actually an internal site hidden by IP so I'm not sure I'll be able to let you browse it. I haven't modified the tagsdiv-article-tag meta box in any way if that is helpful.

It is on a custom post type though with the type as post_type=article. I wonder if I need to qualify that it's on that page somehow?

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem implementing my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery.

First of all, you need to add your script into your `functions.php`

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'expand-tags', get_site_url() . '/js/expand-tags.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts' );
```

Then, in your file (`expand-tags.js`) which is located on, for example, `public_html/mysite/js/`, you will have to have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#link-post_tag").trigger("click");
});
```

**link-post_tag** is the ID of the *Choose from the most used tags* button, so when the page is loaded, a button click will be triggered.

Comment: Thank you so much - worked like a charm!!! Ended up just needing to switch `#link-post_tag` to `#link-article-tag` since the custom-post had some adjustments, but it's perfect.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, glad it helped!